# Executing a runnable in Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runnable

I have a class `AsycnIntegerCounter` which extends `AsyncTask`, with `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` overridden in the same.
From my main thread, I am able to create a runnable object and execute it using the 
`AsycnIntegerCounter`'s static execute method.   `AsycnIntegerCounter.execute(Runnable)`

Can anyone help me in understanding what exactly happens when we execute a runnable using `AsycnIntegerCounter` (i.e) using `AsycnTask` object.

***When this can be used ? and what is the advantage rather than running using a Thread object?***

**Code Sample:**

```
AsycnIntegerCounter integerCounter1 = new AsycnIntegerCounter(next,0);

AsycnIntegerCounter.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                int i = 100;
                while(i<=105){

                    i++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: there is no class called AsyncIntegerCounter, is it a custom class you created?

Comment: yes Onur, its a class which extends AsyncTask, I have mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as `execute()` but it will run your `Runnable` in the background instead of running the `doInBackround` function. It can be useful when you have the same onPreExecute and onPostExecute but several runnables.

I guess the advantage over `Thread.execute` or an `Executor` is exactly calling `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` before and after.

Comment: Thanks for replying Alex, but I could not understand following part "It can be useful when you have the same onPreExecute and onPostExecute but several runnables." 
Also when I execute the runnable using the execute() control does not go to onPostExecute() of the AsycnIntegerCounter class after the runnable has finished its task, is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of fundamental differences between

```
static void execute(Runnable)
```

and

```
AsyncTask execute(Params...)
```

1. Background task is defined in Runnable instead of implementing `doInBackground`
2. The `Runnable`-task is not using the internal thread communication mechanism of the `AsyncTask`. Hence, neither `onPreExecute` nor `onPostExecute` are called.
3. The latter is available on all platforms, whereas the first was added in API level 11.

The advantage of using `execute(Runnable)` is that the task can be executed on a worker thread of the internal thread pool, i.e. no new thread has to be created.

Comment: Also to note that `AsyncTask.execute(...);` uses the default executor which is an instance of `SerialExecutor`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i figure it's like `AsyncTask` class but `AsynchTask` only runs once, but with this class it provides two things-:

1. It loops so it benefits, if you want a task to run multiple time
   like checking for continuous data on a web service.
2. It fixed the running time of a task with Thread.sleep, so if a task finished
   earlier it will fix the time of this task by `Thread.wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

@Alex makes a very good point. Suppose the you have a lot of methods, `M1()`, `M2()`, and so on that you wish to execute. Suppose that before executing any of them you need to execute method `Before()` and after you need to execute method `After()`.

ie, the sequence of methods goes:

```
Before();
M1();
After();
```

Or

```
Before();
M2();
After();
```

By putting `Before()` in `onPreExecute` and `After()` in `onPostExecute` you can achieve that sequence. By making `M` a runnable, you can then achieve:

```
Before();
WhateverRunnableYouWant();
After();
```

With the `Runnable` in a background, non-UI, thread, as per your code.

Comment: Thanks Neil, but when I execute the runnable using the execute method, the control never goes to onPostExecute() or onPreExecute(). Should I add any code to call them in this case??

Comment: Could you post `AsycnIntegerCounter` please to help answer that, thanks.